# Ask for user input, run specified function, then go back to asking

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I am making a CLI in python using click. What i want to have is a kind of "idle state" which the program starts in. The script asks for user input, and depending on the input a specific function should be run. This sub-function can also ask for user input and do different things.

What im having trouble with is making the program return to the "idle state" after the function has completed running.

```
@click.command()    
def cli():
     print "Welcome. What do you want to do?"
     choice = click.prompt('')
     if choice == 'add':
            add()
     else:
            subtract()
```

So after running e.g add() i want to program to once again print "Welcome" and prompt the user for input. Wrapping the cli()-function in a while-loop didn't work - im suspecting click breaks it somehow.

Comment: How exactly did you wrap the function in a while-loop?

Comment: Exactly what happened when you used a while-loop,what "didn't work"?

Comment: I put the While over the choice = click.prompt() line. However the program stops executing after it's done with add(). I just tested removing @click.command() above the add-function, and it then keeps asking for input, so click breaks it somehow :(

Comment: You are correct, the "problem" is decorating `add()` with `click.command()`, as this creates a `Command` decorator that will invoke the function in a [context that will call sys.exit on exit](https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/master/click/core.py#L483).

Comment: Can click call click commands from click commands? I always thought that the click command is where the argument parsing takes place so calling a click command after argument parsing did take place is "wrong".

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
def cli():
    print "Welcome. What do you want to do?"
    choice = click.prompt('')
    if choice == 'add':
        add()
        cli()
    else:
        subtract()
```